# How important is to fix this common Tensorflow warning?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I have seen some people with the same problem, this is the warning:

```
W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/../../lib64:/usr/lib64-nvidia

W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/../../lib64:/usr/lib64-nvidia

W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
```

I have tried installing a few things without luck.

Currently I am testing it in Colab.

What are these libraries and are they worth installing?

Comment: If it does not mess up with your code, don't worry about it

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu , Disagree

Comment: what kind of instance is your Colab notebook running on?

Comment: @Conic standard using GPU, and as far as I know the code uses pytorch only, this is the repo https://github.com/Megvii-BaseDetection/YOLOX, and the google colab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tNWiufDYxB4lNShoIzCmGsY1xLhF-w9s#scrollTo=vHVgSOFRzTI7 thank you for replying